# How do I open a series of continuous forms one at a time?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently, I have the following structure: `Form1` receives inputs. After inputs are recorded, you can click a button to proceed to `Form2` that is dynamically created based on the inputs of `Form1`. `Form2` gathers more inputs that will be used on `Form3`. In each form (i.e. `Form1`, `Form2`, `Form3`), you can go back to the previous `Form` in case you need to change your inputs. **To do this, I will be closing the current `Form`** and opening its `Owner` `Form` that I record manually in my code.

My current method of opening these multiple forms: hiding the current form when proceeding to the next form, closing the current form when backtracking to the previous form. A sample of my code:

```
private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> intData = new List<int>();
    //Process intData's members

    this.Hide();
    SecondInputForm form2 = new SecondInputForm(intData);
    form2.Owner = this;
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Where `next` is a `Button` in my `Form1` that allows the user to proceed to the second form `Form2`. In my `Form2`, I have a similar construct to open `Form3`. However, I have another event listener `FormClosing` to open my previous form `Form1` when `Form2` is closed (i.e. backtracking to previous form):

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{            
    this.Owner.Show();
}

private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> intData = new List<int>();
    //Process intData's members

    EquationInput form3 = new EquationInput(intData);
    form3.Show();
    form3.Owner = this;            
    this.Hide();
}
```

Now the problem occurs here. When I `Hide()` `Form2`, it registers as a `FormClosing` event and somehow closes `Form2` and as a result, closing its 'child' form `Form3`. It then opens `Form1`.

My desired result is: it hides `Form2`, **but does not close it**, and proceeds with gathering inputs from user in `Form3`.

What is the better approach to opening multiple forms **or** how do I fix the current problem if `Hide()`-ing form is indeed the best approach? I feel like using `Hide()` to mimic a series of continuous forms is not really 'intuitive', one might say.

Comment: How shall I improve my question for you to take back your downvote?

Comment: A windows form base class is "Form" so you can create a List<Form> so you can enumerate through the forms.  You can see my two form project on the best way of opening and closing forms. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng So basically, what you did different from me was adding a `Cancel` event on `Form2Closing`. The question is, how do I close the current form to go back to the previous form? Also, is there a documentation about how `Hide()` causes a child form to close?

Comment: Consider creating several pages with `UserControl`s on a `Form`. Doing so you can set their `Visible` property to show the current one and to hide the others. Using forms doesn't seem to me a good approach. According to your description you need to develop a Wizard to collect inputs page by page.

Comment: @Bahrom Sorry, but I've never heard of Wizard. Would this link be a good start in regard to using Wizard in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467446/creating-a-wizard?

Comment: You could go a completely different direction...instead of using Forms, use UserControls.  Then simply change which one is being displayed in some kind of container.  That container can also house the common controls like "next" and "previous".

Comment: Hide doesn't close the form, it just makes the form invisible.  You can still call the public methods to set and extract data or properties.  What do you mean by closing a form?   There is a difference between using the Show and ShowDialog properties.  One is blocking and and the other is non blocking.  To move between forms simply hide/unhide the form, do not dispose.

Comment: @jdweng Please read my description in my question above. The `FormClosing` event triggers for `Form2` when I give a `Click` event on `next` in `Form2`

Comment: Each Form2 should be its own instance.  You can keep a list of the forms either using List<Form> which is a list of any windows form or List<Form2> if you just want  a list of just the Form2.  To keep track of the current active form also have the a variable with the current index in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to handle the problem of you are having is to set the cancel property to true from the FormClosing like this:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();     
    this.Owner.Show();
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

but bear in mind that you should set some sort of condition to close it, else it will never be closed.

Comment: But what causes `Form2` to close in the first place? Was it the `Hide()` method? Is there a link about where I can read this?

Comment: Oh, you cant use modal and hide them, because modals are on top of everything, so your other form gets unaccesible if it is a modal form. You should just use Show(). whenever you call it.

Comment: I see! My problem was on the `ShowDialog()` then. After I decided to `Hide()` the modal form, which cant be hidden, it closes automatically. Correct?

Comment: Exactly that, if you work with the normal show you wont have any problem. Whenever you use a showdialog, you are making the thread that created the form wait for the completion of that form. Im honestly not sure why when hide it closes but my gut tells me is because it can lead to some nasty behaviour. Think that if that form never gets shown again, then you can close the program because it is awaiting for that to finish. I hope i was clear with the explanation.